# Selenium Python selecting dropdown element

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I'm having a lot of trouble finding the web element corresponding to the drop down box directly to the right of **Code:**. I've tried using Select, finding by tag_name, css_selector, xpath, name, class_name, select_by_visible_text, and haven't been able get it. I'm guessing the issue is that the dropdown box is nested within the form tag, highlighted in blue in the picture. The closest I've gotten is this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#code_section_srch form#expertsearchformid select#expertsearchformid:toctextcodeid")))
```

[image]

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use quotas, escape colon or use find by ID:

- `div#code_section_srch form#expertsearchformid select#expertsearchformid\:toctextcodeid`
- `div#code_section_srch form#expertsearchformid select[id='expertsearchformid:toctextcodeid']`

This should work:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "expertsearchformid:toctextcodeid")))
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id='expertsearchformid:toctextcodeid']")))
```